# DTO to hold disparate data from domain model?

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, dto

I have a neat domain model that makes it easy to communicate with an external web service. New requirements have made the external web service's interface messy and now I have to gather data from multiple places in my model. Is a DTO appropriate to hold all the necessary data?

---

I have an interface that deals with searching for some domain models. The concrete implementation behind it goes to an external web service for results.

```
interface IConsentSearch    // only one method
 +Search(Customer) : IList<Consent>

class Customer
 +various properties
```

My domain model is, of course, much more complex, but this is the gist of it.

Now, I got some new requirements that would allow us to search by `order id` in addition to the `Customer`'s properties.
In my internal domain model, `orderId` has its own little place somewhere (not part of `Customer`). The problem is that the external web service interface has a completely different idea of where `orderId` is.

**Note**: it is not an either/or situation: everything `Customer` has to offer is mandatory for the search to take place - `order id` is just an additional criteria.

I am going to have to change `Search()` signature and thought of creating a new DTO in my application service layer called `ConsentSearchDTO`. New DTO would serve one purpose: to combine data and models that are now scattered throughout my domain model and necessary for querying the external web service:

```
interface IConsentSearch    // still only one method
 +Search(ConsentSearchDTO) : IList<Consent>

class Customer      // still the same
 +various properties

class ConsentSearchDTO
 +Customer : Customer
 +OrderId : int
```

My questions:

1. Does the above `ConsentSearchDTO` make sense?
2. Is it ok to create a DTO that references domain model classes (`Customer`) or should I create a whole new structure that mimics the original domain model? This seems like a lot of work and doesn't bring me any additional value.

Comment: That's not really the point of DTOs. They're used to have a coarser granularity when transferring data usually over different processes, or over a network protocol. They're not used to transfer data between layers of a same application. Moreover, the DTO should never appear in your domain layer, it should be broken down into domain objects in your UI/API layer.

Comment: @VincentSavard: Should I treat `CustomerSearch` as a domain model?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, only you can tell, if you do DDD, you're supposed to be the expert of your domain after all! (Or at least have access to domain experts which will help you model the problem.)

Comment: Well, both `orderId` and `Customer` are part of a larger structure. Up until now, it was really easy to call the `IConsentSearch` since all the relevant query data was in `Customer` class. But now, I have to either a) create a new, ad-hoc class simply to bundle up `Customer` and `orderId` or b) create a new method on the interface that has two parameters: `Customer` and `orderId`? Hm... Didn't think of option b) up until this second. Such an approach would go well with the Interface segregation (support your clients!) and wouldn't break the existing domain model with an ad-hoc class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're facing two different problems:

- You have a new requirement: search a `Consent` by an `OrderId`.
- Somehow the API of your search component changed (or needs to change for this requirement).

A change to the web API should not affect the `IConsentSearch` interface. That's the whole point of this abstraction. Anything you have to do to make your application work with the new API must happen in the module that implements `IConsentSearch` (let's call it `WebConsentSearch`).

Now it appears that the new requirement does require a change to `IConsentSearch`.  But the interface must serve the domain model, and be expressed in terms of the domain. So your interface should have a new method such as `SearchByOrderId(Customer, OrderId)` and it's again the job of `WebConsentSearch` to deal with this.

To answer your questions:

1. In the background, `WebConsentSearch` may use all kinds of value objects to pass data between the sub-components that are involved.

   But the term `DTO` or `ValueObject` has no place in your domain layer - and you shouldn't introduce new domain objects just for the purposes of making life easier for your infrastructure. Your domain doesn't "know" what the infrastructure's needs are.
2. In principle, those value objects may have a reference to a domain class. However, in most cases that's not the best idea. Instead, you should probably have an adapter that translates the domain object into a more basic data types that provides that information in a format convenient for your web API client.

   The 'added value' here is that only the adapter will depend on your domain model, making the API easier to change and easier to test.

<sub>[A DTO is, strictly speaking, for *transferring* data between processes. I've changed my answer to use the more appropriate term 'value object' above, though I think it's not uncommon to use the terms interchangeably. In any case, an actual DTO should generally not contain domain objects, because DTOs need to be easily serializable. Also see [here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)]</sub>

Comment: Vincent Savard and you have convinced me that DTO is an unacceptable solution. Plus, I have wondered about DTOs referencing domain classes for some time and this was a great opportunity to ask more about it.

Comment: For sake of completeness, I wanted to clarify what the changes on the external web service API are: absolutely none. They simply instructed us to cram `orderId` in another existing field `customerId`, which obviously has nothing in common with the nature of `orderId`. In my domain model `orderId` and `customerId` are miles apart. Up until that moment our internal model and their interface were rather compatible, but them reusing an existing field for something completely different caught me by surprise.